# Sturm-Liouville eigenvalue problem of order 4

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the eigenvalue problem

$W''''=\lambda W$ with the boundary conditions $W(0)=W'(0)=W(l)=W'(l)=0$.

Has someone a hint how to solve that?

Thank you...

Comment: Do you know how to solve equation $W'''' = \lambda W$ and enumerate all possible types of solutions depending on value of $\lambda$ ?

Comment: Yes, I guess. My problem is actually how to derive $\lambda$ with respect to the boundary conditions...